# How to display an image calculated during runtime with Xlib?

Tags: c++, c, linux, x11, xlib

Is there a way to display a full color image calculated pixel by pixel during runtime using Xlib?

while it has full color the program can be adapted  to mach any color scheme, like rgb, brg or just the hex values for the color.

There is a function called XDrawPoints() that allow for multiple points to be draw, but only one color at a time. If there was a function that could display many colors at the same time it would be very convenient.

Something similar to the bitblt() function from windows gdi would also work very well.

Being efficient is also important because I plan doing some animations later on.

Answer (score 1):

> Something similar to the bitblt() function from windows gdi would also work very well.

Keep in mind that with X11 "client" and "server" can be separated by potentially high latency / low bandwidth link and all calls need to be serialized ( there are exceptions like shared memory images ). To answer your question:

You can use [XPutImage](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XPutImage.html) to draw client side image on a server side "drawable" ( e.i window or "Pixmap". Pixmaps can be used as representation of server side copy of your image ). [XCopyArea](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/XCopyArea.html) is similar to bitblt and allows you to copy images from one drawable to another ( for example, draw previously uploaded pixmap on a visible area of a window )

There are also functions from [XRender](https://www.x.org/releases/current/doc/renderproto/renderproto.txt) extension that allow to combine multiple RGBA images together on a server.